# How to trim the value returned from my database?

Tags: php

I am loading a simple list from a database into an unordered list.

The output displays fine, but the source has unwanted whitespace. E.g.:

```
<li class="loadZip"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($City['City']); ?>
```

Returns:

```
<li class="loadZip">Dallas                </li>
```

How do I trim this?

Comment: You hadn't provided your database schema. If you are using char instead of varchar for storing strings you have to trim it yourself for example.

Comment: You never used `trim` in this code? What is the question?

Comment: `trim(htmlspecialchars($City['City']))`

Comment: why not clean up database and avoid using trim in your code? you can use `update table set \`City\` = TRIM(\`City\`)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option you have is using [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

```
<?php echo trim(htmlspecialchars($City['City']));
```

The other option is to trim this data in your database itself. For example, if you are using MySQL, your query may look like this:

```
select TRIM(City) from table;
```

Comment: @aserwin And make sure that you don't actually include all the spacing in your own code. (like `<li><?php echo ''; ?>  </li>` instead of `<li><?php echo ''; ?></li>`

Answer (score 1):

If Output is array you do something like this for each value

```
$output = array_filter($output); // Remove blank values
$output = array_unique($output); // Remove duplicate values
$output = array_map('trim', $output); // Remove white spaces
```